# load enum map from property file with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

is there a way in spring boot to load a property file and convert into a Map<Enum,Map<String,String>> where Enum is the last part of the name of the single property? here an example:

```
com.example.TEST={'A':'10','B':'100'}
com.example.TEST2={'NAME':'TESTNAME','SURNAME':'TESTSURNAME'}
com.example.TEST3={'WHERE':'TESTWHERE','HOW':'TESTHOW'}
```

and in my configuration class i define this enum

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:testfile.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties("com.example")
public class ConfigurationTestProperty{
    private Map<Enum,Map<String,String>> map;

    public enum Enum{
       TEST,
       TEST2,
       TEST3
    }
......getter and setters
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Enums are primarily compile time constructs. How do you expect that "conversion" to happen? Are you thinking about code generation? This really feels strange. How would you write "client" code that **uses** these enums when they are supposed to depend on the contents of a property file?

Comment: in fact i asked this question to know if there is a solution or a better way to achive my goal, for example changing the property file.

Comment: this enum is created only for a better coherence. but it's not a problem to delete and to manage only string for example Map<String,Map<String,String> where the first key string is the last part of the property name.

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution that consist into changing the properties file structure, writing that like this:

```
com.example.TEST.A=10
com.example.TEST.B=100
```

probably using yml file it will be more clear, but this works perfect, also i change the ConfigurationProperties annotation , adding the prefix parameter "com" and naming my map Map<Enum,Map<String,String>> example.